# Adding Attribute Labels to DynamicModel Yii

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I have dynamic number of questions and answers. I use DynamicModel() for collecting these data.

```
$attributes = [
      "answer_1" => "Some Value 1",
      "answer_2" => "Some Value 2",
      "answer_3" => "Some Value 3",
      .....
]

$customFormModel = new DynamicModel($attributes);
```

I also have

```
$labels = [
      "answer_1" => "Label 1",
      "answer_2" => "Label 2",
      "answer_3" => "Label 3",
      .....         
]
```

I just can't get the $label array to be set as Label Attributes for my Dynamic Model.
My $customFormModel->attributeLabels() is always empty.

These results with the following issue.
I get error messages like these

```
Answer 1 can not be blank
Answer 2 can not be blank
Answer 3 can not be blank
```

What I want instead

```
Label 1 can not be blank
Label 2 can not be blank
Label 3 can not be blank
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$customFormAttributes = array_map(function ($key) use ($attributes) {
    return $attributes[$key];
}, array_flip($labels));

$customFormModel = new DynamicModel($customFormAttributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misuse the `DynamicModel` concept here. This should be used for [ad hoc validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation) and **not** to handle the form presentation as well. If you need to add labels use regular `Model` instead.

You can extend `DynamicModel` and add `attributeLabels()` there and use your new method instead. But what is the point of using DynamicModel when you can just create regular model with everything ready to use?

For custom attribute label you can add `ActiveField` widget method `label()`

```
<?= $form->field($customFormModel, 'attribute')->label('...') ?>
```

or static equivalent from `Html` class `Html::label()`, `Html::activeLabel()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply extend DynamicModel like this :

```
class MyDynamicModel extends DynamicModel
{
    public $attributeLabels = [];

    public function attributeLabels(){   
        return $this->attributeLabels;
    }
}
```

now you can set $attributeLabels as array